# Error with Excon when uploading to rackspace with Fog

Tags: fog, excon

Very recently, uploading of files to Rackspace cloud has started erroring on my mac and one other mac in our office. The same code base works fine on Ubuntu servers and on a third mac in the office.
The error reports an (Excon::Errors::SocketError) Illegal seek (Errno::ESPIPE)
pointing to gems/excon-0.31.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:186:in `pos='"

This has been baffling me for days. All macs are osx 10.9. If anyone can offer any assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

Versions:
Fog(1.20.0)
Excon(0.31.0)

Comment: Does the error happen consistently or just intermittently?

Comment: It happens consistently on two imacs but has no issue on our linux servers(staging and production) and on one mac.

Comment: I have upgraded my version of Fog to 1.26 and this works fine. I did see an issue fixed by @giddie that was similar. I am just trying to understand what could make two dev machines stop working almost simultaneously but not affect others.

Comment: Scratch that. The upgrade went to 1.32. However, it appears that the code never returns from our call to #put_object.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure off hand. Maybe open an issue on fog and I can get one of the rackspace folks to look from there?

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a bit more of a look into it but If not joy I'll raise an issue.